# Form data being lost

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, post

I’ve got a php application in codeigniter and I am experiencing the following issue.
When submitting a form with an Ipad randomly it will lose post data.
I’ve tried accessing the post data in four different ways.

```
print_r($this->input->post());
print_r($_POST);
print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

All of which return nothing or an empty array.
This only seems to happen when using an Ipad or Iphone however it has happened Once out of 50+ tests on a desktop safari.
When testing on a pc browser roughly 100 times (firefox, chrome, IE) it hasn’t occurred, only the one time in safari.

The code for the form;

```
<form id="email_report_form" name="email_report_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/handleajax/email_page" class="email_report_form ajaxform" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <div class="form_step_container clearfix">
        <div class="element clearfix">
            <div class="col_left">
                <label>Email: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col_right">
                <input type="text" name="form_email_to" id="form_email_to"  />
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <label>Separate multiple email addresses with a comma</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element clearfix">
            <div class="col_left">
                <label>Your Message:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col_right">
                <textarea name="form_email_message" cols="125" rows="5" onkeypress="return checkLength(event, this, 1000);"></textarea>
                <label>(Maximum of 1000 characters)</label>
                <br />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_path" id="redirect_path" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element clearfix">
        <i>Information entered in this form will not be used for marketing purposes or passed to third parties.</i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code for the onSubmit validate();

```
function validate() {
    element = document.getElementById("form_email_to");
    addresses = element.value.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) { 
        address = addresses[i].replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
        if (!validateEmail(address)) {
            alert('The email address "' + address + '" is invalid.');
            element.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (window.location.hash.length > 2) {
        $('#redirect_path').val(window.location.hash.substring(2));
    } else {
        $('#redirect_path').val(window.location);
    }

    $('#email_report').slideUp();
    return true;
}
```

Code for the function that the form submits to;

```
public function email_page() {
    echo "<br/>ci<br/>";
    print_r($this->input->post());
}
```

As you can see this is where I am echoing out the post data and at this point the data has been lost.
Does anyone know why I am experiencing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: I think there is no any bugs in code, please check the config.php file, and csrf_protection especially.

Comment: A possible cause could be a 302 or 301 redirect. You submit the form to /handleajax/email_page. If your webserver or php redirects the user to another location, you'll lose your form data. When it is a 301 permanent redirect, most browsers will automaticly go to the new location after they've been redirected once before. This is just one of the many possibilities, but it's easy to check.

Comment: Are you using real ipad or an ipad simulator?

Comment: @jan You can see that i am losing the form data on the first line of the emai_page function and previouse to that there isnt any redirects.

Comment: @Nouphal.M I am using a real Ipad version 5.1.1

Comment: @Rajnish What would I be looking for in the config.php file?Also with CI's CSRF's protection turn off the problem still persists so any configs for CSRF shouldn’t affect it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at this, this guy have found that it is a problem when Negotiate is on on the server, you might check your server or put some sort of negotiation php header, check your Accepts in the HTTP response and play with them, Have a look at this

> Well yeah, I've done all that already and it didn't reveal anything,
>   which is why I asked for help... The failed request trace I posted
>   there was simply the most revealing thing I had to go on.
>
> Figured it out somewhat after digging through all the config of my
>   server vs our test server. Thankfully I had this difference and was
>   able to spot it.
>
> Authentication > Integrated windows authentication > advanced settings
>
> > providers > [Negotiate, NTLM] <-- Does not work Authentication > Integrated windows authentication > advanced settings > providers >
> >     [NTLM] <-- Works
>
> So it looks like it's a bug with safari's authentication stack, where
>   the post body somehow gets screwed up when negotiate is enabled. It
>   doesn't make any sense why that would happen, but really I'm seeing a
>   lot of other odd behavior with authentication in 5.1. A lot of times,
>   but not always, I'll get more than one password prompt when it tries
>   to authenticate the child requests the page makes (css / js / img). I
>   don't think it's a bug with IIS since every other browser even 5.0 is
>   totally fine, plus that NTLM stack should be properly implemented and
>   untouched stable for a long time now... unless a recent windows update
>   in that area could be contributing... that's worth checking out at
>   least. On Monday I'll follow up with the safari folks and see if I can
>   find the underlying issue.
>
> Thanks

Link here http://forums.iis.net/t/1182376.aspx?IIS7+5+receives+empty+post+body+from+Safari+5+1+

Good luck!